# C# WPF Datagrid doesn't dynamically sort on data update

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

I'm having some trouble with my datagrid :

When I update some data (from the model) it shows on my DataGrid, but if click on a header to sort the column it begins to go sideways when I update existing data.

Here's <strike>2</strike> 1 example<strike>s</strike> :

- <strike>If I add a new value, it doesn't appear at the end (like it does when I don't sort the datagrid) but it shows at the wrong place (same place every time).</strike>
- If I update an existing value, the order never changes when it needs to do so.

I've seen multiple answers but some say DataGridTextColumn shouldn't be a problem... <strike>So I was wondering if it was because of the dictionary...</strike>
I know that the first problem with new data had something to do with the dictionary.

Object.

```
    public class Player : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _id;
    private string _name;
    private int _damage;
    private int _heal;
    private int _dps;
    private int _hps;
    private int _time = 1;               

    public Player(string id, string name)
    {
        _name = name;
        _id = id;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Id 
    {
        get { return _id; }
        private set
        {
            _id = value;
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        private set
        {                
            _name = value;                
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");                
        }
    }

    public int Damage
    {
        get { return _damage; }
        set
        {
            _damage = value;                
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Damage");
            Dps = _damage / _time;
        }
    }

    public int Heal
    {
        get { return _heal; }
        set
        {
            _heal = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Heal");
            Hps = _heal / _time;
        }
    }

    public int Dps
    {
        get { return _dps; }
        private set
        {
            _dps = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Dps");
        }
    }

    public int Hps
    {
        get {return _hps; }
        private set
        {
            _hps = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Hps");
        }
    }

    public int Time
    {
        get { return _time; }
        set
        {
            _time = value;
            Dps = _damage / _time;
            Hps = _heal / _time;
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

}
```

ObservableCollection

```
public sealed class ShortList
{
    private static readonly ShortList instance =  new ShortList();
    private ObservableCollection<Player> playerList = new ObservableCollection<Player>();

    private ShortList()
    {
    }

    public static ShortList getShortList
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Player> getPlayerList
    {
        get
        {
            return playerList;
        }
    }

    public void updatePlayer(string id, string name, int damage, int heal, int time) 
    {
        Player player;
        player = findPlayer(id);
        if (player != null)
        {                
            player.Damage = player.Damage + damage;
            player.Heal = player.Heal + heal;
            player.Time = player.Time + time;                
        }
        else
        {                
            player = new Player(id, name);
            player.Damage = damage;
            player.Heal = heal;
            player.Time = time;
            playerList.Add(player);
        }                       
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        playerList.Clear();
    }

    private Player findPlayer(string id)
    {
        foreach (Player p in playerList)
        {
            if (p.Id == id)
            {
                return p;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

XAML

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"Name="playerDataGrid" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nom" Binding="{Binding Name}" MinWidth="35"/>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Degats" Binding="{Binding Damage}" MinWidth="45" />
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="DPS" Binding="{Binding Dps}" MinWidth="29" />
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Soins" Binding="{Binding Heal}" MinWidth="35" />
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="HPS" Binding="{Binding Hps}" MinWidth="29" />
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Code behind the window

```
public partial class MiniParser : Window
{
        public MiniParser()
        {            
            InitializeComponent();
            playerDataGrid.ItemsSource = ShortList.getShortList.getPlayerList;
            temporyFill();
        }

        private void temporyFill()
        {
            ShortList.getShortList.updatePlayer("1234", "ABCD", 100, 0, 2);
            ShortList.getShortList.updatePlayer("1234", "ABCD", 100, 0, 0);
            ShortList.getShortList.updatePlayer("123", "ABC", 50, 0, 1);
            ShortList.getShortList.updatePlayer("234", "ABC", 0, 50, 1);
            ShortList.getShortList.updatePlayer("345", "BCD", 1000, 25, 25);
            ShortList.getShortList.updatePlayer("456", "CDE", 250, 0, 25);
        }

        private void startMI_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ShortList.getShortList.updatePlayer("5678", "BABA", 100, 100, 100);
            ShortList.getShortList.updatePlayer("1234", "ABCD", 100, 0, 0);            
        }
}
```

Of course most of the code behind is there for testing purpose... But the idea is that the model is being updated and the view needs to reflect the changes (Even the sorting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution, so far so good :

The problem was that ObservableCollection doesn't trigger the event "CollectionChanged" when you change the value of a field in an object which is already in your ObservableCollection. (Possibly because you don't change the reference to it).

Here's an example :

```
ObservableCollection<MyObject> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();
myCollection.add("CollectionChanged","Yes");
//Let's say I had a method to find a object with the first string and to change the second string
myCollection.change("CollectionChanged", "No");
```

As you can guess, the second part when I changed a field of my existing object the CollectionChanged didn't trigger...

So the solution I implemented is the following :

```
class ObsCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
    {
        public void UpdateCollection()
        {
            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
                            NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }
    }
```

All you have to do is create the new type of collection and then when you change a field value of an existing object, call the UpdateCollection() method.

This solution is from Wu Xuesong.

I'd like to say Rachel as been also a big help.

Comment: According to MSDN, Reset means "The content of the collection changed dramatically." Is there a more granular way of getting the sorting to work? The Reset seems ok for small collections but could be an issue  for large ones with frequent updates.

Comment: What if you change it from ObservableCollection to BindingList? I suppose BindingList raises collection changed events when individual items change.

Answer (score 3):

You're not raising the `PropertyChanged` event when a property updates. This means that a new item which has `name` changed from `""` to `"Test"`, or an existing item that changes, is not going to raise a PropertyChanged event to let the UI know a value has changed and it needs to update.

To fix it, make your properties raise the PropertyChanged event when they change.

```
public class Player : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name 
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name != value)
            {
                _name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, I was re-reading your question and I have no idea what you're doing with `ObservableDictionary`, but I'd recommend changing that so your DataGrid binds directly to an `ObservableCollection<Player>`. I suspect that's part of your problem.

```
var playerCollection = new ObservableCollection<Player>();
playerCollection.Add(new Player { Name = "Test 1" });
playerCollection.Add(new Player { Name = "Test 2" });
playerCollection.Add(new Player { Name = "Test 3" });

playerDataGrid.ItemsSource = playerCollection;
```

Comment: I think I did what you asked (see changes in the first post), but sadly didn't correct the second part of the problem. Thanks for you help so far I hope I'll find it on my own but I'll keep looking here for my salvation.

Comment: @user1078049 I believe `NotifiyPropertyChanged` is case sensitive, so try adjusting your calls to use the correct case. `NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");`

Comment: Jivlain wrote "In WPF's DataGrid control, if you set a column to one of the default column types (like DataGridTextColumn or DataGridCheckBoxColumn), sort on that column, and then change its value, the grid will automatically be re-sorted."
On an other thread but it's not the case for me... Also I found on the net that it wasn't the case at all

Answer (score 0):

Move any code that looks like this:

```
this.NotifyPropertyChanged("somepropertyname");
```

into the setter methods of your properties. That's what the setters are there for.

Also I second the answer suggestig you use an `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of your `ObservableDictionary<TKey,TValue>`. They are very common for WPF bindings.